# How to prevent falling into the void from killing the player in roblox

Tags: lua, roblox

How do I prevent the player from dying when they fall in the void?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do it is to lift it up the Y-Axis.
I recommend selecting everything then moving it up an **EXACT** amount of studs (e.g. 100) Then just change the script and add 100 studs to all the values.
To be safe I would increase it by a lot more studs than you think you will need.

This is the only way I know of and I think is possible,
Hope this helps.

Comment: ok I will try to be more specific because this is wrong, I meant that there is a mine for digging and if you were digging down you may get into the void, but trying to put the map in a very high Y axis won't be good as I will need to do some things and re-script them for the blocks that you mine, as I scripted something for infinite regeneration of blocks and did it so it doesn't go to the spawn so I added a lot of position values, which will be useless as these positions won't change as I do that, what I want is to prevent you from dying, not from falling to the void

Comment: @rokoblox Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

From [devforum.roblox.com](https://devforum.roblox.com/t/the-ability-to-disable-fallenpartsdestroyheight/126764/27), executing the following

```
workspace.FallenPartsDestroyHeight=0/0
```

from the command bar will set `FallenPartsDestroyHeight` to `nan` which appears to disable the automatic destruction of objects based on Y position.